Problem with addons installing
I just installed the program yesterday
I have problem with installing any addon.
I don't see addons in search. When I try to download or install from extensions.blender.org
it gives an error.


In addition I can say, using the example of the 3D-print addon - it is not searched for in the search, is not added and is missing from the tab. this is with all addons
UPD get extension screen looks like


Hi. I might not understand you correctly. Are you looking in the Get Extensions tab of Edit->Preferences?  Using the example of the 3D Print Toolbox you should find it listed in the Get Extensions tab. Click the Install button and it will then appear, activated, in the Add-ons tab. This method of installing addons changed with version 4.2.

Thanks for your answer. I added my post - Get extension screen also looks very interesting.
Remote refresh do noting

If you have installed portable blender version. Try to follow these steps:

Open blender
Go to Preferences > System > Network
Check this option Allow Online Access.


Allow Online Access has been confirmed.

my problem is looks like https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/124731
but it says that fix was included in one of the latest versions of the program.
but I see the problem in both 4.2.3 and 4.3
